# Wording of notice when dismissing a suggested duplicate

Tags: feature-request, duplicate-questions, wording, plurals

Today someone suggested my question was a duplicate. I contested and selected the NO option in the displayed box. Below is the text I got as response:

[image]

> Thanks! Edit your question to explain how it's different from the suggested questions. This will help prevent your question from getting closed and will remove the suggested questions notification from your post.

Which is a pluralisation error. As only one question was suggested. I think it would be best to have this message use "from the suggested question(s)"